# How this process running in the background?

Tags: javascript, linux, process, nodemon

```
user   1550      1  0 Jun19 ?        00:00:00 node /usr/bin/nodemon src/server.js
user  11051   1550  0 Jun19 ?        00:00:38 /usr/bin/node src/server.js
```

Can someone tell how this process running in the background? The user is not logged in.

Comment: They may have run it with `nohup` so it keeps running when they logout.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: In addition to `nohup`, though unlikely, it could be a `cron` job running under that user's `crontab`

Comment: nohup should be shown in the process right? I checked, no crontab, no screen, no nohup.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are running your nodejs Application using [nodemon](https://nodemon.io/)
nodemon is used to do auto reload when an application crashed. because nodejs is  single thread application, if you did not catch the error safely, it will crash the application. as nodejs is used for server-side application, its needed to use a tool which will do auto restart when its crashed.

you can kill the process by running the below command.

(mine ubuntu):

```
$ kill -9 <proceessId> //here it will nodemon process it
```

Comment: I know that how can I kill it. But have no idea how my friend started this.

Comment: he may ran that application nodemon (like we are using npm scripts, we will start our application using alias command which we configured with our package.json or bash_alias). so it keep running.

Comment: I am not really familiar with this. Can you help me out more?